# Memory in a linked list

Tags: c

I have been programming a simple game in C to learn programming, but I found an error in my code when I work with a linked list.

Here is my `struct`:

```
    typedef struct ListShoots * ListShoots;

    struct ListShoots{
        Shoot d;
        ListShoots next;
    };
```

And my functions about memory:

```
    ListShoots Shoots_Create(int x, int y){
        ListShoots ld = malloc(sizeof(struct ListShoots));
        ld->d.alto = 10;
        ld->d.x = x;
        ld->d.y = y;
        ld->d.v = 6;
        ld->next = NULL;
        return ld;
    }

    void Shoots_Shoot(ListShoots ld, int x, int y){
        ListShoots aux = ld;
        if(ld==NULL) printf("ld = NULL\n");
        while(ld!=NULL) ld = ld->next;
        ld = Shoots_Create(x,y);
        ld = aux;
        if(ld==NULL) printf("ld = NULL (again)\n");
    }
```

When I call the function `Shoots_Shoot` in the main (at first, `ld = NULL`), I get the output: `ld = NULL` and `ld = NULL (again)` too. Why? There should be just the first `printf`, I think, because at first the line `while(ld!=NULL) ld = ld->next` does nothing.

The weird thing is: If I remove the line `ld = aux;`, the output is okay, just: `ld = NULL`.

EDIT: The problem is: `aux` and `ld` are pointing at the same memory because of `aux = ld`. So if I reserve memory for `ld`, immediately `aux` changes and will be not pointing to `NULL`, right?

Comment: You never set `.next` of the last element of the list to point to the new element that you created.

Comment: maybe `ListShoots *ld`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... I get the output: "ld = NULL" and "ld = NULL(again)" too. ¿Why?

Because of

```
ListShoots aux = ld;
/* ... */
ld = aux;
```

You are restoring the original value of `ld`, which apparently is `NULL`, since you are getting

```
ld = NULL
```

from

```
if(ld==NULL) printf("ld = NULL\n");
```

Comment: Yes. But `aux` and `ld` are pointing at the same memory because of `aux = ld`. So if i reserve memory for ld, immediately aux change and will be not pointing to NULL, aren't it?

Comment: No, that is not what happens. When you reserve memory for `ld`, `aux` is completely unaffected by that. To get the behaviour you want, you need another layer of indirection. Use `ListShoots* aux = &ld;` and `ld = *aux;`.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to the specific problem you are describing look at your function

```
void Shoots_Shoot(ListShoots ld, int x, int y){
    ListShoots aux = ld;
    if(ld==NULL) printf("ld = NULL\n");
    while(ld!=NULL) ld = ld->next;
    ld = Shoots_Create(x,y);
    ld = aux;
    if(ld==NULL) printf("ld = NULL (again)\n");
}
```

The first line stores the passed in value of `ld` in `aux` variable. You then print if `ld` is null.

Later you change `ld`

```
ld = Shoots_Create(x,y);
```

but immediately after (before the printf) you do so again **back to its original value** with the next line

```
ld = aux;
```

so essentially both conditionals are testing the same value (the value of `ld` passed to the function). This is why when you remove the line

```
ld = aux;
```

it works - because then you don't change the return value of `Shoots_Create(x,y)` function

Comment: Yes. But `aux` and `ld` are pointing at the same memory because of `aux = ld`. So if i reserve memory for `ld`, immediately `aux` change and will be not pointing to NULL, aren't it?

Comment: But you never change `aux` after initialising it!! You only change `ld` many times. Finally you set it back to `aux` but `aux` is always the same value so both conditionals test the same value. Your `printf` statements will always print zero or two times - never just once. Step through your code with a debugger and you will see whats happening

Answer (score 0):

**-** **aux** and **ld** are pointing to the same memory here:

```
 ListShoots aux = ld;
```

**-** But now if this loop is done at least once they not are pointing to the same memory:

```
while(ld!=NULL) ld = ld->next;
```

**-** Now **ld** points to another space memory due to malloc, while **aux** still points to the same place:

```
 ld = Shoots_Create(x,y);
```

**-** And you remember that you said that **aux** was pointing NULL at the beginning? Well, now **ld** are pointing to the same memory that **aux** again. It means NULL:

```
ld = aux;
```

**Aux** is always the same value (the value of **ld** when the method starts), so both conditionals test always print the same.